# kendoGrid add command and local data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Considering this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sT94F/3/)

When clicking the "Add" button, there's a reference error, "colA is not defined".

Is there a way I can pass an "empty" object when adding the row?

I am using v2012.1.327

Note : I already opened the same thread on kendoui forums [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/add-command-with-local-data.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some time of guessing, I finally got it from the [doc](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration) in section `schema.model`

Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sT94F/6/).